# Ganapati's Birth in relation to writing of Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, ganesha, kali-yuga, vyasa

We know Ved Vyasa told Ganapati to write Mahabharata as he dictated. If a live story can only be written after it is completed, it would mean Mahabharata was written during the start of the Kali Yuga since the war ended in Dwapara Yuga.

Is there a relation of Ganapati's birth to writing of Mahabharat? Does it mean Ganapati was born during the start of the Kali Yuga?

Comment: No. Ganapati was born before Mahabharatha. He was born is this Vaivasvara Manvantara (don't know which Mahayuga). May be beginning of Vaivasara Manvantara as Marriage pf Shiva and Parvati happened during beginning of this Manvantara. Mahabharatha happened in 28th Dwapara Yuga and Vyasa composed Mahabhartha at end of end of Dwapara and during beginning of Kali Yuga.

Comment: So you are saying , Ganapati was born long before 28th Dwapara Yuga?

Comment: Yes. He was born just after Shiva's marriage. When Shiva's seed (URJA) was stolen by Agni, Parvathi Devi made a boy out of mud and dirt. He is Vinayaka and later became Ganapati or Ganesa.